# Webform Conditionals and Email Values

Tags: webforms

The scenario is, I have a form that you order multiple types of stationery. Depending on what items are ordered determines, what email needs to be sent the form results.

The issue I am running into is I need a way to prevent emails from being sent to the other print vendors if their fields are left blank.

Right now they all receive every email it just shows up blank because I have it set to exclude blank fields.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try out the Rules module. It allows a lot of powerful conditions and actions to be configured. You may also pair it with the Webform Rules module to connect it to your Webforms (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules).